# Can I test Arduino Mega ADK using an emulated Android environment?

Tags: android, arduino

I want to play around with using an Android device to control hardware on an Arduino Mega ADK. At the moment I don't have an actual Android device so I'm wondering ... is it possible to use the Android emulator and still talk to an actual ADK board. I went through the "Getting started" [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) and things built and installed as expected but when I run the DemoKit software from the emulated Android environment (GoogleAPI) it doesn't seem to detect the ADK board. I tried unplug/plug, restart, close Arduino programmer to free up the USB connection ... none of which made any difference.

I'm completely new to Android programming so not too familiar with the environment. I have gone through the basic "Hello, world" tutorial using an emulator, but other than that the only thing I've done is build and install the DemoKit app.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is not possible. I don't think the Emulator can actually acccess your USB ports on your personal computer, and thus this will not work.